# Symbol table for Lightning components to find Dependencies/References

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, api, tooling-api

Like we do have SymbolTable for apex class, to **find their references/dependencies**; do we have anything **for the Lightning Components**(to find dependencies/references of lightning components/application/events).

Please let me know, if there are any other(native to Salesforce) mechanisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I remember from one of the Dreamforce session you can do it using **MetadataComponentDependency (Pilot)** . If you can get your company to sign for this Pilot probably that would solve your use case.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm

Comment: That seems quite promising. However, the documentation has ApexClass as MetadataComponentType in all of their example. I guess even SF is not known of existing types(ow it would have been a picklist field with predefined set of values) Playing across the same would help more to understand the same!

Answer (score 2):

To the extent I know of and I can see in the documentation, there's nothing available as of today.

As of now, the Tooling API Objects don't even support any Lightning related features. If you see the [Tooling API guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm), you will see that the Lightning related objects are reserved for future use.

- [Lightning Component Bundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_lightningcomponentbundle.htm)
- [Lightning Component Resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_lightningcomponentresource.htm)

As for finding dependencies, one of the approaches that I have used in past is to search for occurrence of my component across all applicable places just by using an editor search. Other than that, I am not aware of anything that comes out of the box.

Comment: Manual search(or parse) will always help. I was just wondering if we could have in-house  API way to do the same.  Regarding mentioned object, SFDC docs doesn't have much info, so we can't assume the purpose of the objects. Thanks for the time! :-)

Comment: And that's my point. As for the objects, it's not available yet, so you cannot work on it anyways. So you will need to have a workaround here, and unfortunately in this case, it's all manual.

Comment: As of now will try to see if I can avail pilot feature mentioned by Pranay, otherwise will opt for manual parsing!