# Can metadata container contain AuraDefinitionBundle, Layout, FlexiPage, Object?

Tags: metadata, tooling-api, field-dependencies, package-dependency, tooling

I want to build a package to find out metadata dependencies and determine which classes, triggers, pages, components, lightning components and applications, flexi pages, layouts, objects, custom settings, custom metadata objects and records depend on each other.

So far I have found a brilliant way to determine external dependencies for classes, triggers, pages and components described in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60887/how-to-find-dependent-components-for-a-class-page-trigger-using-api-tooling-or) using `MetadataContainer` and creating related `ApexClassMember`, `ApexTriggerMember`, `ApexPageMember`, `ApexComponentMember` records.

However, it is not clear how can I find that, for example, Lightning component is depending on ApexClass and which one or depending on another Lightning component, which custom objects depend on another custom objects or even custom managed objects. How can I find that FlexiPage depends on Lightning component or Layout depends on a Visualforce page?

There are no "AuraDefinitionBundleMember" which I can use for `MetadataContainer` and there are not "CustomObjectMember" or something like that.

Is this possible to implement or should I parse Lightning components, custom object definitions on my own? Can metadata container contain AuraDefinitionBundle or custom object or layout or flexi page?

My question is more generic than [Symbol table for Lightning components to find Dependencies/References](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237126/symbol-table-for-lightning-components-to-find-dependencies-references)
since in my case I am looking for Symbol Table not only for Lightning components, but also for Layout, FlexiPage, Object and other metadata to find dependencies\references.

Comment: My question is more generic than Symbol table for Lightning components to find Dependencies/References since in my case I am looking for Symbol Table not only for Lightning components, but also for Layout, FlexiPage, Object and other metadata to find dependencies\references.

Comment: You can get the list of available objects with Tooling API as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_list.htm). So if you have the components listed there, you can fetch those entities, but anything not documented there is considered not to be available.